# Strange ip address in the log entry on my router

Tags: router, logging

I have an TP-Link N750/WDR4300 wireless router. I look into my logs to day an found a couple of entries that looked like this:

```
Aug 30 06:19:29  DHCP       INFO    DHCPC Send REQUEST to server a123456b 
with request ip 98b1234d

Aug 30 06:19:30  DHCP       INFO    DHCPC Recv ACK from server a123456b with 
ip 98b1234d lease time 18000

Aug 30 06:19:30  DHCP       INFO    DHCPC:GET ip:98b1234d mask:ffffff00 
gateway:33a54321 dns1:a6b09876 dns2:76543fc1 static route:0
```

I've tried search on the internet, but can't find anything that looks similar to this. I do not understand these entries. Can anyone explain these to me?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a hexadecimal representation of an IPv4 address. Using a hex to ip conversion tool (see google) you can retrieve the standard IP notation, which in this case for 98b1234d is 152.177.35.77.

I have no idea why your logs would use the hex format however.

Comment: You were right! Thanx!